# Calling views. Navigator vs class call

Tags: flutter

I'm learning flutter and I recently managed to make the [routes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) work in my project. I also followed [this example](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation) to create a bottom navigation bar.

The thing is, when pressing a button, in the `onPressed()` method I use the `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/endpoint_list');` to access the desired view, but when using the navigation bar, I simply call the class (`fillSecondTab()` and `fillThirdTab()` are just placeholders with a text here):

```
final List<Widget> _children = [
    //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/teacher_view'),
    TeacherView(),
    fillSecondTab(),
    fillThirdTab(),
  ];
```

I wanted to use the Navigator method to access views in the navigation bar too, but it doesn't work. It prompts the following error:

[image]

Why can't I use the Navigator method in the bottom navigation bar?

If I could use it, what would be the difference between a Navigator and a call to the class itself?

Comment: As you said yourself, you are trying to put a method call inside a List of Widgets. That's not how it works. You can see how Navigator is used here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html
You are missing Dart/Flutter/Programming concepts. I would advise you to follow a few basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have created a list of **widgets** but you are trying to return a `Future` (your `Navigator.pushNamed()`), to fix this your code should look like this

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    //views you want to navigate to
     Page1(),
     Page2(),
     Page3(),
  ];

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar StackOverflow'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.android),
            label: 'Android',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.event),
            label: 'Event',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
        onTap: _onTabTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**IN CONCLUSION**

You do **NOT** need to manually navigate with `Navigator.pushNamed()`, this is because `BottomNavigationBar` is designed for navigation.

Hope this helps:))

Comment: So besides the return type error (Future when a Widget is expected), the main thing is that the `BottomNavigationBar` already has a Navigator implemented, so me calling another Navigator makes a Navigator nested in a Navigator, hence why it does not work, correct?

Comment: You got the first part right, navigator is already implemented into `BottomNavigationBar`, so you **CANT** do manual navigation. Therefore it is not that you have nested it, it's just impossible to do. PS An accepted answer and upvote would be great

Comment: Nice, just wanted to make sure I understood I correctly. Thanks for your answer :)